# How does firebase child_added really work?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to read a lot of data from firebase (~3000 children and ~1.5 MB) and it will be good if I can show something that dowloaded to the user. So I decide to use `child_added` to show each one of them, but it's not work as I expect.

After some experiments, I found it will take ~5 seconds at the first child added and a few seconds go to the end (~3 seconds). if I use `value` event it will take ~5 seconds to get them all too.

So my question is how firebase child_added really work? Does it just load them all and trigger an event on each one of them or did I miss something?

**Update**

This is my database structure.

```
- contacts
  - nw7VoNBw0iLUkb
    - city
    - company
    - email
    - name
    - gender
  - BEu8Yd7ihgxbaF
  ...
```

and some of my code

```
console.log('start', Date.now())
firebase.database().ref('/contacts').on('child_added', snapshot => {
  console.log('add', Date.now())
})
```

and

```
console.log('start', Date.now())
firebase.database().ref('/contacts').on('value').then(snapshot => {
  console.log('end', Date.now())
})
```

Comment: Accessing each node takes time. By downloading your data child by child, it would take a significant amount of time more than downloading them all

Comment: I agree but what about the first load? I think it should be faster than load all of them, isn't it?

Comment: Well it's more about the depth of the node. If your first retrieved child is more deeply nested, then it would take a longer time. I suggest you add the database structure to your question. People can help you better that way :-)

Comment: Thanks, I already updated it.

Answer (score 1):

on('child_added') doesn't have a concept of finishing when all of the data is loaded.  It is *always* waiting for a new child to appear that it hasn't seen before, until you turn it off.  The callback could be triggered at any time.  It will possibly load items from a local cache first, if any, in addition to waiting for more items to appear on the server.

If you need a single snapshot of *all* the data at a particular node, just once, and you don't want to be notified about any future changes, just use [once('value')](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once).

It's a good idea to [use the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) to familiarize yourself with the difference between on() and once(), and the different types of events.

Comment: In the docs: `once is equivalent to calling on(), and then calling off()`, so I think there is no different between them in terms of load speed and I don't have a problem with that. My question is about `child_added` and `value` event, I'm just curious why the first load time of `child_added` and load all of them with `value` are slightly the same. Thanks.

Comment: You might be pulling the same data from the cache each time.  Unless you have a lot of data, with some of it uncached, I don't think any performance observation is going to be very meaningful.  Just request the minimal amount of data when you need it, and let the SDK do what's best for performance.